# Can I make Ember template build fail by referencing something that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I think this is a long shot but I am wondering if there is a clever trick that I am not aware of that can give me build time validation for the existing of something in an Ember template.

Say I have something in a template like this:

```
{{ myhelper config=foo }}
```

Is there any way I can trick the ember build process into producing a build error if `foo` doesn't exist? Or is there another way that I can get some build time safety from the template engine?

Comment: Seems like a job for an acceptance-test; not sure how it would be done, since it's by design that foo is allowed to be set asynchronously. Theoretically you can set up a devops system that will reject commits if code isn't covered or tests fail, though I have no experience doing so in practice.

Answer (score 1):

If `config` is `undefined` `throw` an `Ember.assert`.

For example, throw in the `init` hook of a component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  config: undefined,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    if (!this.get('config')) {
      throw Ember.assert('Uh oh config not defined');
    }
  }
});
```

In the console will be an `EmberError`.

[Rendered example](https://ember-twiddle.com/39152761ea63e52abfe95a0202b22005?openFiles=components.my-helper.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-helper.hbs).